# Windows7 Installer takes priority how to move it back during installation using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, windows-7, installation

I've a custom Action on Deployment project of .NET Application, which contains custom dialogbox to enter certain parameters, on invalid parameters I've shown MessageBox.Show - but its being hide by installer window, I tried windows forms too with Activate, TopMost, Focus,bring2front, etc several options but it comes by default behind the windows installer window and due to this user is not able to identify why installing process is not finishing - because actually its waiting for user to read the MessageBox and press OK.

I've tried to implement IWin32Window with the handler of MsiExec Process, and shown the Messagebox but still its not working, anyone has idea ???

Here is my installer.cs function definition

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its solved using IWin32Window only,
problem was there were more then 1 process for Msiexec and I was taking the 1st one as default, but actually my Installer has some other processID not the first one,
so I checked the process.MainWindowTitle Text and considered MainWindowHandle for that process,
and it worked... cheers :-)